# Query not showing expected results for case

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm rather new to more advanced SQL, and I'm testing a stored procedure via removing the stored procedure part and viewing intermediate results.

I'm seeing that my `MemInd` results do not show SF, MF, etc, as expected.

```
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT 
    UMC.CID, UMC.CONCEPT_ID, UMC.STR_VALUE, M.TITLE, M.VF_01
INTO
    #UMC_TMP
FROM 
    DB_DEV..U_MEMBER_CONCEPT UMC WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN 
    DB_DEV..MEMBER M WITH (NOLOCK) ON M.CID = UMC.CID AND M.TITLE = 'RR'
WHERE 
    UMC.concept_id = 501


SELECT 
    T.CID, T.STR_VALUE, T.TITLE, T.VF_01,
    CASE 
       --nullif returns null if 2 expressions equal, otherwise return first  expression
       --isnull returns second value if first value/expression is null; otherwise return first value/expression
       WHEN T.TITLE = 'RR' AND (T.STR_VALUE IS NULL OR T.STR_VALUE = '') 
          THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(T.TITLE, T.VF_01), NULL) -- Title is RR, no member in concept
       WHEN T.TITLE = 'RR' AND T.STR_VALUE IS NOT NULL 
          THEN 'ERROR'   -- ISNULL(NULLIF(T.TITLE,T.VF_01),NULL) -- Title is RR, member ind has a value
       WHEN (T.TITLE <> 'RR' OR T.TITLE IS NULL) AND T.STR_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND T.STR_VALUE IN ('SF', 'MF') 
          THEN T.STR_VALUE    -- This is not returning SF/MP per MemInd col. --ISNULL(NULLIF(T.STR_VALUE,T.VF_01),NULL) -- Title is not RR, member ind has a value
       WHEN T.TITLE <> 'RR' AND (T.STR_VALUE IS NULL OR T.STR_VALUE ='') 
          THEN NULL     -- Title is not RR, no member ind concept
       -- WHEN T.TITLE <> 'RR' AND T.STR_VALUE = '' THEN NULL -- Title is not RR, no member ind concept
       ELSE NULL
    END MemInd
INTO 
    #UPDATES
FROM 
    #UMC_TMP T


SELECT * FROM #UPDATES --this is not showing SF/MF in MemIndicator as expected

DROP TABLE #UMC_TMP
DROP TABLE #UPDATES
GO
```

## UMC_TMP:

```
CID    CONCEPT_ID     STR_VALUE     TITLE     VF_01 
376        501         SF             NULL     NULL 
443        501         SF             NULL NULL 
605        501         MF             NULL     NULL 
550        501                        RR       RR 
876        501                        RR       RR 
970        501                        RR       RR 
183        501                        RR       RR 
726        501                        RR       RR 
542        501                        RR       RR
```

The `#UPDATES` table looks like the following, which has NULL in MemInd all the way down (updated now per Note3). I would expect SF or MF there, or RR

```
CID    STR_VALUE      TITLE   VF_01    MemInd
---------------------------------------------

550                   NULL     NULL      NULL 
876                   NULL     NULL      NULL 
970                   NULL     NULL      NULL 
183                   NULL     NULL      NULL 
726                   NULL     NULL      NULL 
376     SF            NULL     NULL      SF 
443     SF            NULL     NULL      SF 
605     MF            NULL     NULL      MF 
542                   RR       RR        NULL
```

So it looks like both RR from the first case isn't getting to the MemInd column, as well as the SF/MF from the STR_VALUE, third case, isn't getting to the MemInd column.  Any ideas?

I'm  not seeing why MemInd of #UPDATES is not correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I updated the #UPDATES to show VF_01.  I think the first case is ok now (RR is already set in VF_01), **but** the 3rd case should show SF/MP/SF47 in MemInd when Title<>RR and STR_VALUE is not null. It doesn't have any funky isnull nullif for that to make results unclear.

Note2: I added the result of the UMC_TMP table

Note3: I changed T.TITLE=NULL to T.TITLE IS NULL in the 3rd case, and MemInd seems to be correct now.  I updated the #UPDATES table accordingly in the question and the CASE statement.

Comment: If the column `MemInd` is filled with `NULL` then that means that none of the `WHEN` expressions were True, or those that did evaluated to `NULL`. Without sample data, or expected results, there's little else we can tell you here.

Comment: On a different note, why are you using `NOLOCK` everywhere in your first query? You *do* understand the implications of using such a query hint, correct?

Comment: Learn GOOD habits. First, format your code so that it is readable to others. You buried the END corresponding to the BEGIN on the 2nd line. Terminate your statements. Stop applying the <select ... into ...> pattern blindly. Using DISTINCT is often a kludge to cover up a logic or schema flaw. Mixing AND and OR within a series of logical comparisons usually requires parentheses - which is SOP for any language.

Comment: @SMor - If you have suggestions to show, that would be great. I am adding some parenthesis into my case. I will update the question.

Comment: @Lamu - you can see the data in the table in the question.  It also shows the results.

Comment: @SMor - I put the Begin in my comment. I never used Begin/end before, so if you have helpful info, that would be great.

Comment: I added more data to the table in the question to show VF_01

Comment: I added (TITLE<>'RR' OR TITLE=NULL) in question since there are null titles but results didn't change

Comment: TITLE = NULL doesn't make any sense, it will always be false.  You want IS NULL.

Comment: I'm not sure what your intent was with this statement: ISNULL(NULLIF(T.TITLE, T.VF_01), NULL).  NULLIF compares the two values and returns NULL if they are equal.  So if both title and vf01 = RR you wanted to return NULL.  Then you had an outer ISNULL which says if the first argument is NULL, then return NULL.  So you're getting all NULLS for the data with title = RR as that is what the first case evaluates to.

Comment: See my previous comment for the correction on the third condition.  All the rows in your data are matching the first condition or the third condition, once fixed.  So you'll have NULLs for the RR rows and SF/MF for the other three rows.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @WillRickards - For the 3rd case, it's TITLE<>RR, so for cases of STR_VALUE SF/MF (which aren't blank or null), it should be setting MemInd to SF/MF.  Those cases exist in the above data.

Comment: @WillRickards - Wow. I made the change to fix =NULL in the 3rd case, and it seems to be giving the correct results in MemInd now for SF/MF cases.  I totally didn't expect that. Thank you so much. I need to take a look and figure out how that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @WillRickards, the fix was discussed above:

```
WHEN (T.TITLE <> 'RR' OR T.TITLE IS NULL) AND T.STR_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND T.STR_VALUE IN ('SF', 'MF') 
          THEN T.STR_VALUE
```